# Code Completion of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, code-completion

When I use code completion of Android Studio,it always shows only default constructor of object, not  constructor with attributes.How to show all constructor of object using code completion(ctrl+space)

Comment: That is a statement.  What is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Press `Alt+Insert`, a code completion popup menu will appear. The first item should be `Consturctors` so press Enter. Now a dialog will appear which will let you select

- constructors from superclass to override
- create a new constructor based on field variables which you choose

Answer (score 0):

If I autocomplete while typing a class name, Android Studio normally completes the name with no parameters listed. I then use the (Mac) shortcut `command-P` to list all available parameter combinations. It won't fill parameter values for you (obviously), but it lets you see what is available. I'm sure there's a corresponding Windows shortcut to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it.In Android Studio,File>Setting>Editor> check "Insert selected variant by typing dot,space..."